# Expected value of function of negative binomial

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

With $X$ representing the total number of trials, and m the fixed number of successes. The pdf is then

$f(x|p)=$${x-1}\choose{m-1}$$p^m (1-p)^{x-m} \ \ \ \ x \ge m$

As a step in something else I'm trying to find $E[\frac{1}{X-1}]$.

---

Here's what I've got up to now:

$E[\frac{1}{X-1}]=\sum_{x=m}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-1}$${x-1}\choose{m-1}$$p^m (1-p)^{x-m} \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \ $   #lotus

$E[\frac{1}{X-1}]=(1-p)\sum_{x=m}^{\infty}(x-m)$${x-2}\choose{m-1}$$p^m (1-p)^{x-1-m} \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \ $ #algebra

$E[\frac{1}{X-1}]=(1-p)\sum_{y=m-1}^{\infty}(y+1-m)$${y-1}\choose{m-1}$$p^m (1-p)^{y-m} \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \ $ #let y = x -1

Note the first term of the sum is zero to change the starting index.

$E[\frac{1}{X-1}]=(1-p) \left[ \sum_{y=m}^{\infty}y P(y|p)+ (1-m)\sum_{x=m}^{\infty} P(y|p) \right] \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \ $ #splitting up the sum

$E[\frac{1}{X-1}]=(1-p)\left[ \frac{m}{p} + (1-m) \right] \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \ $ #left = expectation of negative binomial, right = pdf sums to one

Is this correct? Is there a neater way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{x=m}^\infty\frac1{x-1}\binom{x-1}{m-1}p^m(1-p)^{x-m}\\
&=\sum_{x=m}^\infty\frac1{m-1}\binom{x-2}{m-2}p^m(1-p)^{x-m}\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{p^m}{m-1}\sum_{x=m}^\infty\binom{x-2}{x-m}(1-p)^{x-m}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{p^m}{m-1}\sum_{x=m}^\infty\binom{-m+1}{x-m}(-1)^{x-m}(1-p)^{x-m}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{p^m}{m-1}\sum_{x=0}^\infty\binom{-m+1}{x}(-1)^x(1-p)^x\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{p^m}{m-1}p^{-m+1}\tag{5}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{p}{m-1}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
$(1): \binom{x-1}{m-1}=\frac{x-1}{m-1}\binom{x-2}{m-2}$

$(2): \binom{x-2}{m-2}=\binom{x-2}{x-m}$ and bring constants out front

$(3): \binom{x-2}{x-m}=\binom{-m+1}{x-m}(-1)^{x-m}$

$(4): x\mapsto x+m$

$(5):$ binomial theorem

$(6):$ algebra

Comment: thanks for the great answer. On step 3) - I'm not familiar with that manoeuvre, does it have a name I could look up? Much appreciated.

Comment: @conjectures: there is some description in the [Wikipedia article on Negative Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution). Basically, it is
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{-n}{k}
&=\frac{\overbrace{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)\cdots(-n-k+1)}^{\text{$k$ terms}}}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\frac{(n+k-1)(n+k-2)(n+k-3)\cdots n}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Blessed is Wikipedia :) Much appreciated.